# Retrieving Data From Multiple Tables in a LINQ to SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm new to LINQ and I'm not sure how to retrieve data from multiple tables from my SQL server database, here's the query:

```
SELECT cp.*, tsd.Action, tsd.CurrencyPair 
from TradeStatsData tsd, CalculatedPrices cp 
where tsd.TradeID = cp.TradeID and cp.Price is null and cp.ActiveTime < GETDATE()
```

The database uses the variable connection

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sql query would be something like this in LINQ:

```
var result = from tsd in TradeStatsData
             join cp in CalculatedPrices on tsd.TradeID equals cp.TradeID
             where cp.Price == null && cp.ActiveTime < DateTime.Now
             select new
             {
                CP = cp,
                Action = tsd.Action,
                CurrencyPair = tsd.CurrencyPair
             };
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq is very similar to sql, just a little backwards.

```
from tsd in TradeStatsData
join cp in CalculatedPrices on tsd.TradeID equals cp.TradeID
where cp.Price == null && cp.ActiveTime < DateTime.Now
select new { cp.Col1... cp.ColN, tsp.Action, tsp.CurrencyPair }
```